# Hibernate session load entity from cache

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, locking

I have the requirement to lock an Entity on its first read. i.e. I would use the session.load() first to read an entity, if it fails, then I use session.get(). First time an entity is read by session using get(), I would mark it as locked (lock is transient property, not persisted in DB). I am assuming next time when I call session.load(), I would get the entity marked as locked, from the cache, instead of retrieving it from DB again. But this is not happening. session.load() always fails and goes to the catch block to use session.get(). Not sure where my understanding is wrong. Appreciate any help. Also suggest me if there is any better way to achieve this.

```
        entity= service.load(id);
        try{
            entity.getBookingNo();
        }catch(LazyInitializationException e){
            entity= service.getById((id));
        }
        if(entity.getLock()){
            return "Record locked by another user";
        }
        entity.setLock(true);
```

Comment: load() gets you a proxy object. If the object is not in your DB exception will be thrown when you access the entities methods

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the strategy you're using above will work in a multiuser or clustered environment.

You should consider using [Hibernate Pessimistic locking](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-locking) which can apply database level locks to your data.